# Failed to import bridging header swift Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-signin

Trying to use the Google Sign In API and I get this error consistently.

```
GGLCore/GGLCore.h' file not found
#import <GGLCore/GGLCore.h>

<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header
```

I have looked around for solutions but nothing has seemed to work. I checked all of the search paths and it looks good. Also my bridging file is definitely linked in the settings. I have also tried cleaning and updating cocoapods.

Bridging Header:

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
#import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
target "Sell Goods" do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
    pod 'OneSignal'
    pod 'TextFieldEffects'
end
```

Comment: Did it work?? Have you checked the answer?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The second solution did not work. For the first solution it didn't prompt me to add a new bridging header. I tried creating a header file but it didn't work.

Comment: Then, there is totally an error inside the Bridging Header, most likely because it cannot import those headers. You can go to your project's directory in Terminal and type pod update. Then run the xcworkspace again and see if this works. Might also try rebuilding the project

Comment: Alright I will try that, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause for this would be that the **`Bridging Header`** is not properly connected to your project.

### Solution 1:

I strongly recommend deleting your current **`Bridging Header`** and then go to `File` -> `New File` -> `Objective-C Source File(.m)`. When you create the file it will ask you if it should create a new `Bridging Header`. Click `Create`. After that, put your `#import` statements in the new header, and delete the `.m` file, which is unnecessary. Then, you're good to go.

### Solution 2:

To check if your **`Bridging Header`** is connected properly to your project, go to `Project` -> `Build Settings` -> `Swift Compiler - General`. There, you will have the option Objective-C Bridging Header.

The value of ***Objective-C Bridging Header***  should be:

***`YourProjectName/YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`*** as shown in the image below:

[image]

Please note that your `Install Objective-C Compatibility Header` must be set to `YES`. If the name of your **`Objective-C Bridging Header`** is not set as described above, please do that manually.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It certainly will NOT ask you automatically if you want to create a bridging header. An extremely unclear response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nearly identical problem, it arose after adding a build configuration, scheme, info.plist attribute, and a couple unused classes.  (Not sure which caused the problem).

I did 2 things, not sure which fixed it for me.

**1)** ran `pod update` from the project root directory

**2)** cleaned the project (Top menu bar, Product -> Clean)

Then the project ran with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by going to Framework Search Paths and ensuring all of the values were in quotes " ". Hope this helps someone!